# Basic question about Integration (Monotocity)

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Why is
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}xf(x)dx\geq \int_{a}^{\infty}af(x)dx
$$
assuming $f(x)\geq 0$ and $a>0$. Is it because the integral is only defined for $x\in[a,\infty]$ and otherwise $0$ so that $x\geq a$?

Comment: Are you assuming $f(x)\ge0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes thank you very much. in my case, f(x) is a pdf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, one thing you can think about is that $$\int_a^\infty xf(x) \ \text{d}x - \int_a^\infty af(x) \ \text{d}x = \int_a^\infty \left(x-a \right)f(x) \ \text{d}x  $$ And over the whole region of integration $x \geq a$ so that $(x-a) \geq 0$ and we have also that $f(x) \geq 0$ so that $$ \left(x-a\right)f(x) \geq 0$$ which gives $$\int_a^\infty \left(x-a \right)f(x) \ \text{d}x \geq \int_a^\infty 0 \ \text{d}x = \lim_{b \to \infty}\left. \left[0 \right] \right|_a^b = \lim_{b \to \infty}0 = 0 $$ so that, altogether $$ \int_a^\infty xf(x) \ \text{d}x \geq \int_a^\infty af(x) \ \text{d}x$$

Answer (score 2):

If $F(x)\leq G(x)$ on $[a,b]$, then
$$
\int_a^b F(x) dx \leq \int_a^b G(x) dx;
$$
this can be proven by looking at the Riemann sums. On $[a, \infty)$ we have $x\geq a$, so $xf(x)\geq af(x)$ for any $f(x)\geq 0$, and the required inequality follows.

Hope this helps!